# Marshal C++ union in C# that contains a pointer to an array

Tags: c#, marshalling

I have a problem creating a structure layout in C# that corresponds to the one in C++ so it can be marshaled. Here's the types that should be marshaled in C++:

```cpp
enum E1
{
};

enum E2
{
};

struct Foo
{
    int foo1;
    int foo2;
};

struct UnionField1
{
    int uf11;
    Foo* uf12;
};

struct UnionField2
{
    int uf21;
    int uf22;
    int uf23;
};

struct UnionField3
{
    int uf31;
    int uf32;
};

struct Bar
{
    E1 bar1;
    union
    {
        UnionField1 bar2;
        UnionField2 bar3;
        UnionField3 bar4;
    };
    E2 bar5;
};
```

And here's my variant of them in C#:

```cs
public enum E1
{
}

public enum E2
{
}

public struct Foo
{
    public int foo1;
    public int foo2;
}

public struct UnionField1
{
    public int uf11;
    public Foo[] uf12;
    //public nint uf12;
}

public struct UnionField2
{
    public int uf21;
    public int uf22;
    public int uf23;
}

public struct UnionField3
{
    public int uf31;
    public int uf32;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Bar
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public E1 bar1;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public UnionField1 bar2;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public UnionField2 bar3;
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public UnionField3 bar4;
    [FieldOffset(24)]
    public E2 bar5;
}
```

If I try to do something like `Marshal.SizeOf<Bar>()`, I get the error **"System.TypeLoadException : Could not load type 'Bar' from assembly '..., Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it contains an object field at offset 8 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object field."**

However, everything works fine if I change the field `UnionField1.uf12` to the one commented out (`nint` instead of `Foo[]`). My question is why is that and is there a way to make this layout work with array representation so that I won't be required to convert `Foo[]` to `nint`?

As far as I understand `Foo[]` and `nint` should be marshaled in the same way in terms of memory layout, packing, etc am I wrong?

I also tried adding to `UnionField1.uf12` attributes `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]` and `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]` but it didn't help.

Comment: It is much like the exception message says, the array is overlapped and that prevents the garbage collector from reliably determining its address.  Guessing wrong would cause horrible corruption that is impossible to diagnose.  Use int* or Marshal.Copy() or Marshal.ReadInt32() to marshal yourself.

Comment: When marshalling gets non-trivial, you're often going to have to do everything yourself - sending raw unmanaged pointers, not arrays, and dealing with things like pinning : yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't overlap a reference-type object field with any other type. An array is a reference-type.

You are going to have to marshal the array manually into a pointer.

```cs
public struct UnionField1
{
    public int uf11;
    public nint uf12;
}
```

Make sure to release the memory in a `finally` to avoid leaks.

```cs
var size = Marshal.SizeOf<Foo>();
var ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size * YourArray.Length);
yourUnion.bar1.uf12 = ptr;
try
{
    for (var i = 0; i < YourArray.Length; i++)
    {
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(YourArray[i], ptr + i * size, false);
    }
    // make call
}
finally
{
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
}
```